# Scraping a changing value without charging the web page each time

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to scrape a value that is changing every second from a website. But for a time reason i don't want to dowload each time the websit page.
After some research, i couldn't find any tips with Beautiful Soup.
Any idea of tips will be usefull !

Thanks in advance.
Here is my code

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

time_start=time.perf_counter()
cours_sp500 =0

link="https://fr.investing.com/indices/us-spx-500-futures"
headers={'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36'}

source=requests.get(link,headers=headers).text
soup=BeautifulSoup(source,"html.parser")

classe_sp500 = "top bold inlineblock"
real_time_website ="bottom lighterGrayFont arial_11"

for div in soup.findAll('div', {'class': classe_sp500}):
    cours_sp500 = div.text

for div in soup.findAll('div', {'class': real_time_website}):
    real_time_website = div.text

cours_sp500_split = cours_sp500.split()
sp500_time = real_time_website.split()

valeur = cours_sp500_split[0]
tendance = cours_sp500_split[1]
percentage = cours_sp500_split[2]

time_finish=time.perf_counter()
print("\nA", sp500_time[0],"\nValeur :", valeur, "\nTendance:", tendance, "\nPercentage:", percentage)
print ("\nTemps :",time_finish - time_start, "secondes" )
```

Comment: unless you know the exact position of where that text is on the website, this is impossible. if you do,  however, you can download only a specific range (if the server supports HTTP 2)

Comment: You mean reduce the time by only downloading the changing value eachtime ?

Comment: You should not, but you could request one or many specific Ranges in Bytes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Range_requests#Requesting_a_specific_range_from_a_server (in case the server supports it). But i assume, this is not very reliable.

Comment: Thank you for this solution ! Why shouldn't i do that ? Is it a problem from an ethic point of view ?